# Getting electric shocks from the oven and risks from nearby gas installation

Tags: electrical, kitchens, gas

I recently moved to a new rental flat (Portugal) and set up a contract with a gas company. As part of the installation process the gas company sent an inspector to ensure that gas could be installed safely. The inspector found there was an electric leak coming from the kitchen towards the gas installation (he got a small shock when touching the gas pipes). I called an electrician who fixed the issue and the next time the inspector came he found no issues and gas was successfully installed.

However, yesterday I got a shock when turning on the oven (which is precisely the part of the kitchen the electrician worked on). I contacted my landlord to explain her the issue and ask her to send someone to fix it but in the meanwhile I have completely turned off the gas. I would like to know whether it is safe to continue using the gas until the problem is fixed and what are the possible hazards of continuing to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the gas company hooked up gas you should be OK to use the gas. The gas company normally would check the appliances for any gas leaks after turning the gas on. If you're not smelling any gas they did a good job. The bigger issue is why are you getting shocked from the oven. You need to keep hounding your landlord to get this fixed. Your oven is  electric and that would be some pretty high voltage so it's nothing to treat lightly. Try wearing sneakers or turn off the circuit breakers for the oven.

Comment: As long as Portugal adds the stink smell to their gas, as they do here.

Comment: Thanks! The oven is electric, I could use it when I had electricity in the apartment but no gas yet

Comment: Something has a ground fault, it maybe the range, or something else like an electric HW heater or???  Since I don't know enough about European electrical systems, this is just a comment, not an answer.   In the USA, both hot and cold water pipes (if metal), gas pipes, need to be connected to a ground bar in the main panel and the ground bar needs to be connected to a grounding system (ground rods or Ufer). Your range may not be grounded at all and have an internal ground fault.  The other possibility is a faulty grounding system in the flat you're renting.  ...continued in next comment. ...

Comment: ...continuing ... does anything else give you a shock when touching it? If so, something has a ground fault and the grounding (Earthing in EU speak?) system has a failure.   To diagnose, I'd get a meter and measure from a metal point on the range to a known, good ground (earth), if you have a voltage there is an issue.    Next:  Is the shock continuous or instant?  Might just be a static electricity shock. Only a meter reading can tell for sure.   Wish I knew more about EU electrical systems, so I'm just saying what's common here in the USA.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson thanks for the comment. The shock is continuous if I touch the front piece of the oven when it is running (if the oven is off there is no shock).

Comment: @Salmorejo  you isolated the problem. awesome. 2 more comments: that it would shock means it's not properly grounded and 2) there is most likely a serious ground fault caused by the oven's heating element or connections.   Often wires in ovens fail due to the heat.    All you can do is unplug it (or turn off the breaker if hard-wired), pull it out, take off the back and inspect for damage to the wiring.   What you have going on is pretty dangerous and really needs to be fixed. Oops, wait, it's a rental, so your landlord will need to address this.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I tried again and I got shocked even with the oven off. I will press my landlord to get the issue fixed as soon as possible. Until then, how can I minimise the risk?